# c: a.exe has stopped working

Tags: c, arrays, function, crash

I am learning how to program in c:

I want to create a program that separates a number into digits, from there I want to store them into an array (which I've already done in the code below). From there I need to print out the number by using the digits to help with producing the same number. The program crashed upon running and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    //Issue: printing out incorrect numbers
    //Fix: Recall that c is treated as a character here when getchar is invoked

    #define MAX_SIZE 100
    const int TEN = 10;
    const int ONE = 1;

    int c;
    int digitPos, digitHolder, numberPower = 0;
    int my_strg[MAX_SIZE];


    printf("\n");

    while (((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n'))
    {

        my_strg[digitPos] = c - '0';
        digitPos = digitPos + ONE;
    }

    while (digitPos >= 0)
    {
        int toPower = digitPos - 1;
        printf("%10d", power(TEN, toPower));
        digitPos = digitPos - 1;
    }


    return 0;
}

int power(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return a * power(a, b - 1);
    }

}
```

Currently the output is the powers required to return the inputted number, but after the print, the program crashes. Could someone please guide me in the right direction as to how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Try to initialize `digitPos`. E.g.: `int digitPos = 0`

Comment: and `while (digitPos >= 0)` --> `while (digitPos > 0)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY since I couldn't recreate OP's stack smashing (that's why I oversaw the actual problem. I hope ;-) ) I tried to find out why and it seems as if GCC (4.9 here) is able to optimize it to tail-recursive with `-O2`  and upwards. That together with GCC's wrap-around signed int overflow made it work, but, yes, it is still undefined behavior, of course.

Comment: I was able to fix it after changing the second 'while' loop to a 'for' loop

Answer (score 0):

Change the while condition  `while (digitPos >= 0)` into  `while (digitPos > 0)`

Because when `digipos`==0 --> `toPower`==-1 --> `power(TEN, toPower)` **CRASH**

### Beside that tiny problem your code is fine